# Cant import/export React components in visual studio

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying something that I thought would be very basic but for some reason its just not working at all!

I'm simply trying to create 2 simple react components in 2 different jsx files and import one of them to the parent file and then use and render the child component in the parent one.

I have created a simple mvc site that simply goes to the index page that imports the selected jsx file which the first component is in. Reactjs is installed via nuget package manager. I'm still learning reactjs so I'm probably doing something glaringly wrong for this to not work.

I have tried using requires and es6 import/export but neither seem to work for me.

specifically using the import/export methods throws a syntax error even though I have both node.js and typescript installed in visual studio!

Any help would be great.

Please see code below:

Component1.jsx:

```
import Component2 from "./Component2.jsx"

class Component1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>hello</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Component1 />,
    document.getElementById('test')
);
```

Component2.jsx:

```
class Component2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Component2;
```

Comment: @JanickFischer That would only work if `Component2` was a named export. They're using the correct syntax for importing a default export.

Comment: Also I don't have webpack installed and a lot of posts seem to say that helps but I'm confused why this doesn't work the way it is currently!

My project settings and resharper are both set to es6 as well so I'm presuming its not an issue with the compiler but again I could be wrong as this is very new to me.

Comment: Check out this tutorial for React in Visual Studio ASP.NET. Scroll down to the Transpilation section and that's what you'll need to follow: https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-use-react-with-visual-studio-and-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @Chase DeAnda can you add your comment as a solution so I can accept it as a solution.

That was exactly the problem, took a bit of work as the correct configs were not always in the right place but in an essence once webpack and babel were correctly setup as in the Transpilation section of that blog everything just worked

Comment: @Deepam Yes and thank you I appreciate that! Glad you got it working.